# нужно написать код на js прибавляет 1 если число >= 0

Tags: javascript, html5

я вроде накидал код, но проблема в том что js прибавляет 1 как строку

```js
const numbs = []
const number = document.querySelector('#txt' ) 


const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', updateButton);
function updateButton() {
    if ( number.value >= 0 ){
   numbs[1] = number.value + 1; 
   document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = numbs[1]  ;
 }   else{
    numbs[0] = number.value;
    document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = numbs[0];

 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="number" name="" id="txt">
    <button class="btn">проверить</button>
  <h1></h1>

    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Значения из полей формы являются строками, поэтому преобразовывайте их к числовому типу, иначе при сложении вы получаете обычную конкатенацию строк. `+number.value +1;` или `parseInt()` / `parseFloat()`. P.S. Код у вас избыточный, подумайте над оптимизацией

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение и оптимизация кода.

```
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
    
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const number =  parseInt(document.querySelector('#txt')?.value);
  document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = number >= 0 ? number + 1 : number;
});
```

В данном коде используется стрелочная [функция](https://learn.javascript.ru/arrow-functions-basics).
Также используется [тернарный оператор](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Надеюсь код вам поможет.

Answer (score 0):

можете попробовать написать так:

```
numbs[1] = +number.value + 1;
```

оператор "+" приведет тип **number.value** к number и будет произведено сложение двух чисел, а не строк. если же вы хотите в numbs[1] сохранить не number, а string, то вам следует написать так:

```
numbs[1] = `${+number.value + 1}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Это код js который выводит окно prompt и потом к числу прибавляет единицу если меньше нуля то выводит строку undefined

```
    var question = prompt("Введите число");
    if(question>=0){
  console.log(question+"1")
    }else{
  console.log("undefined")}
```

Comment: Здесь может получиться конкатенация строк, а не прибавление 1.

Answer (score -2):

```
numbs[1] = number.value + 1*1;
```

Comment: Посмотрите внимательно на свой код ...

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]